# Getting #error when call view from Snowflake in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a View in Snowflake. Inside View Joining 2 Tables and calculating a column `SUM(F1.StockOnHand_qty * D1.ItemPrice ) As COST`.   Datatype of Column `StockOnHand_qty`  in Table F1 is `NUMERIC(38,0)` and Datatype of Column `ItemPrice` in Table D1 is `NUMERIC(32,16)`.

When I call this view in SSRS Report and Adding SUM(COST), getting #error for few records and rest of rows are coming with right figure. When I run same query in Snowflake there is no error.

Have other people faced same issue..?

When I add CAST function like below then also throwing same error.

```
CAST(SUM(F1.StockOnHand_qty * D1.ItemPrice) AS DECIMAL(15,8)) As COST
```

How to fix this? Why at 1st place SSRS giving #error.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing when you run it directly in the Snowflake UI with the CAST() function?  Is there a pattern you can see in the numbers that are erroring out when you add the CAST()?  You are changing the precision of your number with that CAST() function, so perhaps you are creating issues with that.

Comment: I am not getting any error in Snowflake. I am getting error only when trying to get data using SSRS. Getting error before using CAST. I thought Adding CAST can solve the problem but It did not.

Comment: You may have to CAST both columns  `SUM(CAST(F1.StockOnHand_qty AS DECIMAL(15,8)) * CAST(D1.ItemPrice) AS DECIMAL(15,8)) As COST`

Comment: I have tried that too and still same issue